# Error using rails Mail_form gem: "uninitialized constant Mailform"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications, html-email, form-for

So, I've checked all the existing answers to similar questions here on stackoverflow and elsewhere, but cannot get the mail_form gem to work as advertised.

Here's the setup: I'm trying to create a simple lead capture form for my company's website. I want to email the data collected by the form to my email account without a database backend and I thought that's what mail_form would make easy.

Here is my model, `ContactForm.rb`:

```
class ContactForm < Mailform::Base
  attribute :name,     :validate => true
  attribute :email,    :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :file,     :attachment => true
  attribute :phone 
  attribute :referral
  attribute :message
  attribute :nickname, :captcha => true

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def headers
    {
      :subject => "New Lead",
      :to => "jonthewineguy@gmail.com",
      :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
end
```

And here's my controller, `contact_forms_controller.rb`:

```
class ContactFormsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact_form = ContactForm.new
  end

  def create
    begin
      @contact_form = ContactForm.new(params[:contact_form])
      @contact_form.request = request
      if @contact_form.deliver
        flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your interest!'
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        render :new
      end
    rescue ScriptError
      flash[:error] = 'Sorry, something was wrong'
    end
  end
end
```

And here is my view, `contact_forms/new.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for @contact_form do |f| %>
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, :required => true %>(required)<br /><br><br>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, :required => true %>(required)
  <br /><br><br>
 </div>
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :phone %>
  <%= f.phone_field :phone %><br /><br><br>
 </div>
  <div class="field">
  How did you hear about us?:<br /> <%= f.text_field :referral
  %><br /><br><br>
 </div> 
  <div class="field">
  Comments (What types of wine are you
  interested in?):<br / <%= f.text_area :message %><br /><br><br>
</div>
 <div class="field">
  Submit: <%= f.submit "Create" %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

I'm pretty new to rails and web programming in general, so it might well be that I am missing something REALLY basic here that isn't mentioned in any online tutorials. I've been all over the mail_form documentation and every tutorial and answer I can find and I'm still getting the error.

Oh yes! I also get the error if I try ContactForm.new in the rails console.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Oh yes, Rails version 3.1.1

Comment: Your model file should be named `contact_form.rb`, that's the rails convention. You're also mentioning an error, could you add it to your question?

Answer (score 6):

If you're trying this for the first time from console, be sure to restart your rails console after installing your gem.

Answer (score 4):

you have a typo in your class definition

```
class ContactForm < Mailform::Base
```

should be

```
class ContactForm < MailForm::Base
```

also make sure you installed mail_form added

```
gem "mail_form", ">= 1.3.0"
```

to your Gemfile and run bundle install